# How can I resolve "configure.ac: not using Gettext ... Libtool Automake"? Autoconf error in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, configure, autoconf

I am new new to GNU/Linux and compiling. I am not able to compile [Aegisub](https://github.com/Aegisub/Aegisub) from source.
On GNU/Linux Debian 7.7 Wheezy amd64, when running sh autogen.sh in Aegisub I get the following output:

```
$ sh autogen.sh 
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is used, but not AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Automake
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
Now run ./configure and then make to build Aegisub
```

With `W all`:

```
$ sh autogen.sh -W all
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=all 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
configure.ac:28: warning: The macro `AC_GNU_SOURCE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:28: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:314: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
configure.ac:28: the top level
configure.ac:128: warning: The macro `ACX_PTHREAD' is obsolete.
configure.ac:128: You should run autoupdate.
m4macros/ax_pthread.m4:87: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:128: the top level
configure.ac:393: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:393: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:207: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
m4macros/wxwin.m4:507: WX_ARG_ENABLE_YESNOAUTO is expanded from...
m4macros/wxwin.m4:572: WX_STANDARD_OPTIONS is expanded from...
configure.ac:393: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:631: gt_INTL_MACOSX is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:418: AM_ICONV_LINK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2764: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:418: AM_ICONV_LINK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
autoreconf: configure.ac: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is used, but not AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=all
configure.ac:28: warning: The macro `AC_GNU_SOURCE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:28: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:314: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
configure.ac:28: the top level
configure.ac:128: warning: The macro `ACX_PTHREAD' is obsolete.
configure.ac:128: You should run autoupdate.
m4macros/ax_pthread.m4:87: ACX_PTHREAD is expanded from...
configure.ac:128: the top level
configure.ac:393: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:393: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:207: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
m4macros/wxwin.m4:507: WX_ARG_ENABLE_YESNOAUTO is expanded from...
m4macros/wxwin.m4:572: WX_STANDARD_OPTIONS is expanded from...
configure.ac:393: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:631: gt_INTL_MACOSX is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2687: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:418: AM_ICONV_LINK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
configure.ac:441: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:441: You should run autoupdate.
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2764: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2031: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2052: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:418: AM_ICONV_LINK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:71: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:441: the top level
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=all
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Automake
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
Now run ./configure and then make to build Aegisub
```

Output of `autoupdate -v`

```
$ autoupdate -v
autoupdate: running: echo dumpdef | /usr/bin/m4 2>/tmp/augdPQm8/m4.defs >/dev/null
autom4te: formatting traces for `/tmp/am4twRarw5/dependencies': include, m4_include
autom4te: up_to_date (autom4te.cache/traces.2): outdated: aclocal.m4
autom4te: the trace request object is:
autom4te: $VAR1 = bless( [
autom4te:                  '2',
autom4te:                  0,
autom4te:                  [
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf'
autom4te:                  ],
autom4te:                  [
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4',
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4',
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4',
autom4te:                    'aclocal.m4',
autom4te:                    '/dev/null'
autom4te:                  ],
autom4te:                  {
autom4te:                    '_LT_AC_TAGCONFIG' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_F77_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_INIT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_pattern_forbid' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_IF' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_TARGET' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_SUBST' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_SRCEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_HOST' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PATH_GUILE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AU_DEFINE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_CONFIG_LTDL_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_LINKS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_sinclude' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_SUPPORTED_TAG' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_MAINTAINER_MODE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_NLS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_PP_DEFINE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_GNU_GETTEXT_INTL_SUBDIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_m4_warn' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_CXX_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_ENDIF' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_ENABLE_MULTILIB' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_SILENT_RULES' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_MOC' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_FILES' => 1,
autom4te:                    'include' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_INIT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_define' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_AR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_GNU_GETTEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_LIBSOURCE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_FC_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_BUILD' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_FREEFORM' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AH_OUTPUT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_PP_SRCEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'sinclude' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_CC_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_pattern_allow' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_XGETTEXT_OPTION' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_CONDITIONAL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_HEADERS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_DEFINE_TRACE_LITERAL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_POT_TOOLS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'define' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_include' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_ELSE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_SUBST_TRACE' => 1
autom4te:                  }
autom4te:                ], 'Autom4te::Request' );
autom4te: running: /usr/bin/m4 --nesting-limit=1024 --gnu --include=/usr/share/autoconf --debug=aflq --fatal-warning --debugfile=autom4te.cache/traces.2t --trace=AC_CANONICAL_BUILD --trace=AC_CANONICAL_HOST --trace=AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM --trace=AC_CANONICAL_TARGET --trace=AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR --trace=AC_CONFIG_FILES --trace=AC_CONFIG_HEADERS --trace=AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR --trace=AC_CONFIG_LINKS --trace=AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS --trace=AC_DEFINE_TRACE_LITERAL --trace=AC_FC_FREEFORM --trace=AC_FC_PP_DEFINE --trace=AC_FC_PP_SRCEXT --trace=AC_FC_SRCEXT --trace=AC_INIT --trace=AC_LIBSOURCE --trace=AC_PROG_LIBTOOL --trace=AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE --trace=AC_SUBST --trace=AC_SUBST_TRACE --trace=AH_OUTPUT --trace=AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION --trace=AM_CONDITIONAL --trace=AM_ENABLE_MULTILIB --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT_INTL_SUBDIR --trace=AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE --trace=AM_MAINTAINER_MODE --trace=AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE --trace=AM_NLS --trace=AM_PATH_GUILE --trace=AM_POT_TOOLS --trace=AM_PROG_AR --trace=AM_PROG_CC_C_O --trace=AM_PROG_CXX_C_O --trace=AM_PROG_F77_C_O --trace=AM_PROG_FC_C_O --trace=AM_PROG_MOC --trace=AM_SILENT_RULES --trace=AM_XGETTEXT_OPTION --trace=AU_DEFINE --trace=LT_CONFIG_LTDL_DIR --trace=LT_INIT --trace=LT_SUPPORTED_TAG --trace=_AM_COND_ELSE --trace=_AM_COND_ENDIF --trace=_AM_COND_IF --trace=_AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE --trace=_AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE --trace=_LT_AC_TAGCONFIG --trace=_m4_warn --trace=define --trace=include --trace=m4_define --trace=m4_include --trace=m4_pattern_allow --trace=m4_pattern_forbid --trace=m4_sinclude --trace=sinclude /usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4 /usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4 /usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4 aclocal.m4 /dev/null > autom4te.cache/output.2t
autom4te: formatting traces for `/tmp/am4twRarw5/warnings': _m4_warn
autom4te: reading /tmp/am4twRarw5/warnings
autom4te: formatting traces for `-': AU_DEFINE, define, m4_define
autoupdate: running: /usr/bin/autom4te --language=autoconf --verbose --include=/usr/share/autoconf --trace AU_DEFINE:'_au_defun(@<:@$1@:>@,
autoupdate: @<:@$2@:>@)' --melt /dev/null >/tmp/augdPQm8/au.m4
autom4te: formatting traces for `/tmp/am4txRH1xM/dependencies': include, m4_include
autom4te: up_to_date (autom4te.cache/traces.2): up to date
autom4te: the trace request object is:
autom4te: $VAR1 = bless( [
autom4te:                  '2',
autom4te:                  1,
autom4te:                  [
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf'
autom4te:                  ],
autom4te:                  [
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4',
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4',
autom4te:                    '/usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4',
autom4te:                    'aclocal.m4',
autom4te:                    '/dev/null'
autom4te:                  ],
autom4te:                  {
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_F77_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_LT_AC_TAGCONFIG' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_pattern_forbid' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_INIT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_TARGET' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_IF' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_SUBST' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_HOST' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_SRCEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PATH_GUILE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_CONFIG_LTDL_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AU_DEFINE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_LINKS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_SUPPORTED_TAG' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_sinclude' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_MAINTAINER_MODE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_NLS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_PP_DEFINE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_GNU_GETTEXT_INTL_SUBDIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_m4_warn' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_CXX_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_MAKEFILE_INCLUDE' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_ENDIF' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_ENABLE_MULTILIB' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_MOC' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_SILENT_RULES' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_FILES' => 1,
autom4te:                    'LT_INIT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'include' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_define' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_GNU_GETTEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_AR' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_LIBSOURCE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_BUILD' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_FC_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_FREEFORM' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_FC_PP_SRCEXT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AH_OUTPUT' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_pattern_allow' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_PROG_CC_C_O' => 1,
autom4te:                    'sinclude' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_CONDITIONAL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_XGETTEXT_OPTION' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_CONFIG_HEADERS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_DEFINE_TRACE_LITERAL' => 1,
autom4te:                    'define' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AM_POT_TOOLS' => 1,
autom4te:                    'm4_include' => 1,
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_ELSE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_SUBST_TRACE' => 1
autom4te:                  }
autom4te:                ], 'Autom4te::Request' );
autom4te: formatting traces for `/tmp/am4txRH1xM/warnings': _m4_warn
autom4te: reading /tmp/am4txRH1xM/warnings
autom4te: formatting traces for `-': AU_DEFINE
autoupdate: running: /usr/bin/m4 --include=/tmp/augdPQm8 --include=/usr/share/autoconf /tmp/augdPQm8/input.m4 > /tmp/augdPQm8/updated
autoupdate: 'configure.ac' is unchanged
```

autogen.sh contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo Running autoreconf...
autoreconf -ivf "$@"

echo Now run ./configure and then make to build Aegisub
```

Version information:

```
$ ./configure -V
Aegisub configure aegisub_version
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69

$ autoconf -V
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

$ automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.11.6

$ gettext -V
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.18.1

$ libtool --version
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2
```

What does these outputs mean and how can I resolve them?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your question is nice and all with the logs and version info, but it's not clear what you want. The instructions are right in the output.

Comment: I wonder why I get these errors(?) occur and why I get them. I failed to compile the code using `make` and `checkinstall`? If it is necessary I will provide those logs as well, but I thought to start where the problems begin.

Comment: They're not errors. It does not say "error" anywhere in your logs. What it does say is, "Now run ./configure and then make to build Aegisub". Did you run `./configure` and `make`?

Comment: Do you mean it is safe to ignore, for example, "configure.ac: not using Automake"? They seem important since I failed to compile the program using `./configure`, `make` and `checkinstall`. If it is necessary I will provide those logs as well, but I thought to start where the problems begin.
And concerning the obsolete macros, it still gives me the same (or similar) warnings after I have run `autoupdate`.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the output: `autogen.sh` just invokes `autoreconf` to initialize the GNU build system. Warnings about deprecated functions are annoying, but something to worry about for the maintainer. To help you, please provide the output of the failing `make` call.

Comment: This answer to a similar question may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378813/47778